# How can I reorient this window arrangement?

Tags: vim-windows, window-management

In vim I currently have this window arrangement

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|             1              |
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|             2              |
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|             3              |
+----------------------------+
```

This is what I want:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|             |              |
|             |              |
|    1        |      2       |
|             |              |
|             |              +
+-------------+--------------+
|                            |
|             3              |
+----------------------------+
```

How can I do that?

If I focus on 1 - then try to convert the `1 & 2` horizontal split to vertical  with `<C-w>H` I end up with this

```
+------+------+
|      |      |
|      |   2  |
|  1   +------+
|      |      |
|      |   3  |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the windows arranged as in you last illustration, move the cursor to window 3 and type `<C-W>J`.

Comment: cool, thanks. I see from `:h ctrl-w_j` this is pretty much a command for exactly that! i.e. `Move the current window to be at the very bottom, using the full width of the screen.  This works like closing the current window and then creating another one with ":botright split",  except that the current window contents is used for the new window.`